# Is it possible for type narrowing to affect a generic type parameter within a TypeScript function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is it possible to get TypeScript to correctly infer the type of the `callback` param inside the `funcAorB` function? It is able to infer the type of the `callback` param from the caller's perspective when calling `funcAorB`, but not inside the body of `funcAorB`. I was hoping that since TypeScript is able to determine the correct type of the `data` param, due to the `switch` statement testing the `key` member, that it would also use that same type wherever the `T` generic type is used within the function.

I like that the type of `callback` is correctly inferred when calling `funcAorB`, I just wish I could get that same inference inside `funcAorB`.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOBBKBeKBvAUFKAnCOAEwHsA7AGxCgGsIQAuKAcjmYBosBfAbiy1CRYCOACE0mHPkKlK1OoxYAjDtz5YAZgFcyAY2ABLclG16kACiIim8REnZRdcChSVxdNJpevC7ASjQAPigANxIDIgCMLk0dfSMyEzjRb0QbEVEHJxc3Dy8rNN8xANRgsIiomNi9Q2NTXSQSPFEAHgAVKAgAD2AIMiIAZyKUAB8i0UDUuCY2rOdXd08oKZmSsvDIyVwBgHcDYF0AC2WCuAA6BSipXCcB6FZmJmxcF6gAejeoNvAIAGVdPAGMDAKBKCAUAwQEIQIbAQ4IKCnKAGIYkDRQQTQWzIKBkEg7M7XF4fKCiLTABwASSg8OhGJIUC0dygACI4AMWaCIE4mdBvpB-oDgRjDgYyDRYfDgETcCTsgsPI44IkwcsVsM1qENlAxursaJNeVIoTXrh6hZTnMcosoOyTj5sUhDRs-HxTaCCHAaG6XjFXrd7ionjL3p9+X8AUCQWCIVCYSKEUiUVA0RifuNcfiTaaSWSKVBqbToMAGbzWezOWCeczw4KoyKxRKE9L3XL5rkaEqVdBzHqRE6glqIjr7YV9c6KtnXvUUpaldbFXa+4gDYOja6Q0pPd6iX6oDEqiS2odoPKO2mhMmxRoIHgCEQoGA8CRIHgqLaQXDT-MoAN9hBCXNJoUgwWh6CYB59wcKZNWeUMvlFIYBi0XRdAgCBBi5atoCTIZr1ve96S5YZs10cgBhBaYWDYCRTgueg+C4DcsCPE95wVTtMWRPCyBvO8MMfZ9X3fBEv3Y39-0AuJGmacxQIUCCVCg0c4FgqRWOTZDUPQzCqzgMtcORXiCIEktiP1UjyOjRTmFokR6JARjXSAA)

```
type DataA = {
  readonly key: 'a',
};

type DataB = {
  readonly key: 'b',
};

function funcA(data: DataA, callback: (data: DataA) => void) {}
function funcB(data: DataB, callback: (data: DataB) => void) {}

function funcAorB<T extends DataA | DataB>(data: T, callback: (data: T) => void) {
  switch (data.key) {
    case 'a': {
      // TypeScript believes that data is of type DataA now.
      // But, I have to use "as" because TypeScript thinks that
      // callback can be ((data: DataA) => void | (data: DataB) => void).
      funcA(data, callback as (data: DataA) => void);
      break;
    }
    case 'b': {
      // TypeScript believes that data is of type DataB now.
      // But, I have to use "as" because TypeScript thinks that
      // callback can be ((data: DataA) => void | (data: DataB) => void).
      funcB(data, callback as (data: DataB) => void);
      break;
    }
  }
}

// The callback type is inferred properly at the call site.
funcAorB({ key: 'a' }, (data) => {
  // This succeeds because data is inferred to be DataA.
  const a: 'a' = data.key;
});

// The callback type is inferred properly at the call site.
funcAorB({ key: 'b' }, (data) => {
  // This succeeds because data is inferred to be DataB.
  const b: 'b' = data.key;
});
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards

Comment: TypeScript is unable to narrow generic type parameters via control flow analysis; it is technically correct not to do so, but it's a big missing feature and pain point for people implementing generic functions.  See [ms/TS#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) and [ms/TS#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) for proposals that might help here...

Comment: ...For now you either have to use assertions, or consider refactoring to something like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mMXGdN) as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109). Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz The info about the proposals alone is actually what I would accept as the answer. The refactor is helpful too, but in my case I'm trying to make a functional React component that takes two props, a state object (`DataA` or `DataB` for example), and a setter callback to update that state. The component determines what type of data it is and then renders the proper subcomponent (`RenderDataA` or `RenderDataB`, for example), passing the data object and setter callback as props to that subcomponent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript currently cannot use [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to narrow or re-[constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter.  It [can](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-3.html#contextual-narrowing-for-generics) narrow the apparent type of a *value* of a generic type, but the generic type parameter itself will stubbornly stay the same.  So `data` is narrowed to `DataA` or `DataB`, but `T extends DataA | DataB` is not changed.

One reason for this is because TypeScript's type system can't currently express what would need to happen to `T`.  Imagine if someone made this call:

```
const dA: DataA = { key: "a" };
const dB: DataB = { key: "b" };
const dAorB = Math.random() < 0.5 ? dA : dB;
funcAorB(dAorB, data => { data.key /* "a" | "b" */ });
// function funcAorB<DataA | DataB>(
//   data: DataA | DataB, callback: (data: DataA | DataB) => void
// ): void
```

Here `T` is specified with the full [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) type `Data | DataB`. So it would be incorrect to narrow `T` to just `DataA` or `DataB`, and it would be incorrect to re-constrain `T` to `T extends DataA` or `T extends DataB`.  By checking `data.key`, you'd only be able to add a *lower-bound* `T` as described in the feature request [microsoft/TypeScript#14520](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14520), maybe of the form `T super DataA extends DataA | DataB` or `T super DataB extends DataA | DataB`.  But there's currently no way to write that in TypeScript currently.

If TypeScript *could* do that, then it would probably notice that the `callback` passed to `funcA` would have to be of a type between `(data: DataA | DataB) => void` and `(data: DataA) => void`, which would be safe, and your function would compile without error.  But it can't, so it doesn't.

---

There are a few open feature requests asking for support for control-flow-based generic re-constraining.  One is [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) which would allow you to index with a generic index as if the type parameter were lower bounded.

Another is [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808), which would explicitly prohibit unions in the specified type parameter.  After all, I imagine you don't actually care about supporting the `dAorB` case from above, and would like to tell the compiler: "look, `T` will either be `"a"` or it will be `"b"` but it will absolutely not be the union `"a" | "b"`".  If we *could* to that with something like `T extends_oneof "a" | "b"` or `T extends_oneof("a", "b")`, then presumably the compiler could treat type parameter narrowing like value narrowing, and things would magically work.

Anyway if you care about this being supported you might want to go to these issues and give them a .  But pragmatically speaking it's best not to assume that will do anything and just work around it.

---

The easiest workaround would be to just use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) as you've been doing.  More difficult is a refactoring to use generics as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), so that your `funcAorB` body would do a single thing seen as correct by the compiler (e.g., `funcs[data.key](data, callback)` for an appropriately generic `funcs`).  Since you mentioned that this won't work for your use case I won't go into it further here.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOBBKBeKBvAUFKAnCOAEwHsA7AGxCgGsIQAuKAcjmYBosBfAbiy1CRYCOACE0mHPkKlK1OoxYAjDtz5YAZgFcyAY2ABLclG16kACiIim8REnZRdcChSVxdNJpevC7ASjQAPigANxIDIgCMKC5NHX0jMhN40W9EGxFRBycXNw8vK3TfMQDUYLCIqJj+UwTjWqQSPFEAHgAVKAgAD2AIMiIAZ2KUAB9i0UC0uCY27OdXd08oKZnS8vDIyVwBgHcDYF0AC2XCuAA6BSipXCcB6FZmJmxcF+SzKbncxag4IZXhtahDZ+PivXBKAhwGigl6xV63e4qJ7XF61VKnT4LDw-P6nDKIUSAiqRGGvCGEaEouHVWL8XTkAbAKBEJD45ASaIKJgAIjg3JifHpZEZzNEbPE6E59B5Sn5vCwQpFLKaEqgAFkEIczng4P0SABbcwBFpQAAMZwArFAAPzMlBMIiiPgNFWWRrNBynIKYZkiC70KAAegAVFBefyxtzZVBg4GYiCsIG47VDPV4u7WrZ2WMsxNzIm47g8cMoDnMpi8kt-lnRuMiRsC1A-Exifwk1A2odoDksTQoIJoAYhgYyBoIHgCEQoGA8CRIHgqD8mcAu455lABvsIGc4mZXVLFA8Yg4poDnkG452hxutLpdBAIIMoEoIE4tHdfYgoNeR2OJ4-+xIZ9oBrHcbgZJlphYNgJFOf0QD4LgE0bTtu3mSt+3AQdh1HcdJ2nWd50XBB+1XHsNy3HcXWacwDyYZgVGPE4RDPKR2yvIYBlve9HyGF83w-L0f1w-8p2AICX3GMDHAg596MY9A4IURDkLIOB9QgAYwHcaAACUIA0dxxLwLZMKEGsORRSFZEXLloNUXB5SkAdxks15rPIWzpWUByBX4XAU0SN5dAsYsawrRYCh8Gt60qH1qUCtM9HRaLyzXL58mYopc1izZolpKRFSZAB9WohklFEoIaTgySYNEpGpFyADF4nKn0AG0AGlvySBQSA0MyIH6qBStagBdBgUX+aIPLkWhvO6rgIsy6bpGITz5AW+NvWJXKGsK2SyqYFq9Da0bTv84LUySajWm67pen6IY+oGk7dAGSZixmmQNvmxRFuWqsvrWmzNv+7ayiBOLz1wAhgC0PAbta9qlPoMaPnS3sE0cy72LI9Dvhc4S-3wmc53HYjl3xlwKN6aTbtov76JgpasrgVjXjx68uLvB8n34uB32gIScJJgDxOA4ZpPA4VIOZ5hYL9ZSGuQ3A8bQjK+yJ0W8IAsmiOoEiVw1ihae3KQGbonymNPb0YYvDtDm57i+b419BcEkRvx10TAMl3NpZk2W5OtxSlfoGEkPULggA)